# Permanent variables for batch files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

My program is a GUI based install and run tool for a certain program, when I say GUI, I mean batch files. When it installs a program, it needs to always know where it is installed, currently, it just records it into a variable, but that only works if they don't shut the program and return at a later date, so I wanted to know a way of storing a permanent variable.
I was thinking maybe something like this:

```
set instloc='C:\Users\JoeBloggs\Documents\Environment\My Programs\This program.exe'
echo %instloc% > instloc.txt
attrib +h instloc.txt
```

But I was wondering if there was a dedicated command for it

Comment: `setx instloc "C:\Users\JoeBloggs\Documents\Environment\My Programs\This program.exe"`

Comment: The registry was invented for that purpose. The are many SO articles about how to read and write registry entries in batch.

Comment: Well there is an oxymoron - equating GUI (Graphical User Interface) with batch files.

Comment: use SETX - setx modifies the value permanently, which affects all future shells, but does not modify the environment of the shells already running. You have to exit the shell and reopen it before the change will be available, but the value will remain modified until you change it again.

Comment: So in our world, GUI means console.

Comment: Do not use single-quotes `'` in `cmd`/batch files, use double-quotes `"` instead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Set*** modifies the current shell's environment values, and the change is temporary but available immediately. The change will not affect other shells that are running, and as soon as you close the shell, the new value is lost.

***setx*** modifies the value permanently, which will affect in all future shells, but does not modify the environment of the shells already running. You have to exit the shell and reopen it before the change will be available, but the value will remain modified until you change it again.

In your case, instead of using *set* use *setx*:

> setx instloc "C:\Users\JoeBloggs\Documents\Environment\My Programs\This program.exe"

Comment: Did you actually bother to test your answer? `setx` does not use `=`. It should be `setx instloc "C:\Users\JoeBloggs\Documents\Environment\My Programs\This program.exe"

Comment: @DavidPostill: Thats a typo. The person who is writing can easily figure it out. I just gave the difference and how to use it.

Comment: @David. If u know that instead of commenting here, why don't u edit that.Then no point of these all. I have changed it and thanks .